# Move comment with cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there some way to cut & paste / move a cell **including** its comment ?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?  When I try cutting and pasting a cell in Excel 2003 the comment moves with it.

Comment: Yep, comments also move in Excel 2010 with cut/paste.

Comment: Tracked it down, I had been trying out a clipboard manager and it looks like it only pulled over the cell content, not the comment, when I did CTRL+X, CTRL+C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by the other comments cut and paste does carry the comment over with it. As far fetched as it may be, is it possible you have comment indicators turned off and they in fact are there, but just aren't displaying?